# Node.js - Mongoose not accessing DB in included package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

I have started working of late on MEAN technologies;

I have a module myModule. It has routes, services, models accessing database.

I have created another project, myAnotherModule in a separate directory, and have "npm link" ed it into myModule. While I try to use Mongoose in myAnotherModule, it is unable to access DB with proper credentials.

In the following code in myAnotherModule,

```
var db  = mongoose.connection.db;
var mongoDriver = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new grid(db, mongoDriver);
```

it does not find the `mongoose.connection.db` and `db` is undefined. 
Whereas if I use these lines in myModule, then the code works fine.

Why is myAnotherModule not able to find `mongoose.connection.db`? 
How does npm link work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect following way :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});

exports.test = function(req,res) {
  res.render('test');
};
```

Comment: I donot want to establish a new connection in myAnotherModule; I have already got the connection established in myModule; Why is mongoose not being shared in myAnotherModule? Am I required to do anything else, which I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter this issues recently as well. Typically people separate db config thus cause this problem. Try to declare in proper block that ensures mongodb is already connected.

```
  db.once('open', function callback () {
        var gfs = new grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoDriver);
   });
```

Comment: I think I did not make my issue clear; I shall try again.

Comment: I think I did not make my issue clear; I shall try again.  I have a main module. Main module has routers, services, models. It has a mongoose connection established.    I have added another   package, moduleB; ModuleB also has routers, services, models.  I have "npm link"ed moduleB in my main module.   In moduleB, I am facing this issue of not getting access of mongoose related information.   I tried what you have suggested in moduleB, still same problem;  Once npm linked, is not moduleB part of main module? then why is it not gettinng mongoose object?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?